# DataTable Column CaseSensitive in Turkey

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-2.0

I have a customer in Turkey who had a problem recently that he couldn't use one of our components. The component is written in C# .Net 2.0 and uses a `DataTable` which has several columns. If I access a column by name on my computer(Region Germany and Language German) then the component works. If I execute the component on a turkish computer(Region Turkey and language Türkçe) it fails to execute properly.

I narrowed the problem down to case sensitivity. If I access a column by name and the name is written with an uppercase letter instead of lowercase letters then it fails on the turkish computer. The strange thing for me is, that it won't fail on my computer. Both machines are Windows 10.

I have created an example to make this problem reproducable.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet set = GetDataSet();
        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in set.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                String Directory = string.Format("{0}", row["component"]);
                String FileName = row["name"].ToString();
                String compBig = String.Format("{0}", row["compId"]); //here is the problem. I wrote the compId with an uppercase I instead of i

                String component = String.Format("{0}", row["component"]);
                String name = row["name"].ToString();
                String compSmall = row["compid"].ToString();
            }  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        DataSet set = new DataSet();

        DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Table0");

        workTable.Columns.Add("component", typeof(int));
        workTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
        workTable.Columns.Add("compid", typeof(Guid)); //Here is the compid with a lowercase i

        DataRow row = workTable.NewRow();
        row["component"] = 0;
        row["name"] = "AName";
        row["compid"] = Guid.NewGuid();

        workTable.Rows.Add(row);
        set.Tables.Add(workTable);
        return set;
    }
}
```

The Exception is as follows:

[image]

**My question is:** Why is it in one situation case sensitive and in another one case insensitive?

I solved the problem for now, by changing the uppercase I to lowercase i (which it should have been from the get go)

--- ***UPDATE:*** ---

I have tried it now with several cultureInfos

```
        CultureInfo culture;
        //uncomment to test
        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR"); //turkish fails
        //culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL"); //Hebrew works
        //culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA"); //Arabic works
        //culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"); //English works
        //culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"); //Russian works
        //culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"); //German works
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

until now turkish seems to be the only one where it fails.

--- ***Update*** ---

I tried the following:

```
        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR"); //turkish fails
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        String ID = "ID";
        String idLower = "id";

        Console.WriteLine(ID.ToLower());
        Console.WriteLine(idLower.ToUpper());

        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR"); //Greek works
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        Console.WriteLine(ID.ToLower());
        Console.WriteLine(idLower.ToUpper());
```

which results in:

[image]

It seems that the toLower() of the uppercase "I" is different in turkish then in other languages.

Comment: Usually the Turkey issues are due to culture being right-to-left instead of left-to-right.

Comment: @jdweng i tried it with setting the cultureInfo to turkish which makes the error reproducable on my machine. By Setting it to Arabic or Hebrew, which are both right-to-left if i am not mistaken, it wont reproduce the error

Comment: @jdweng I have updated my question to adress the issue you have mentioned. Thanks for the Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a toLower() on the string "compID" with the turkish region settings. If it will returns "compID" the türkisch case sensitive is another than the West European one. Actually I can't check it, because I have no computer here.

Comment: interesting thought, but the String.toLower() works fine. Thanks though for the idea.

Comment: I have changed cultureInfo before the toLower() and it seems that it is really a different one. It is an "i" without the dot. It is really subtile but it is different